# Dynamically expanding a scipy array

Tags: python, scipy

Is there a way to dynamically expand an scipy array

`from scipy import sci`
`time = sci.zeros((n,1), 'double')`

Can we increase the size of `time` array after this?

Comment: sci is not standard, explain it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible to expand arrays using the `resize` method, but it can be a slow operation for large arrays, so avoid it if possible<sup>*</sup>.

For example:

```
import scipy as sci
n=3
time = sci.zeros((n,1), 'double')
print(time)
# [[ 0.]
#  [ 0.]
#  [ 0.]]

time.resize((n+1,2))
print(time)
# [[ 0.  0.]
#  [ 0.  0.]
#  [ 0.  0.]
#  [ 0.  0.]]
```

<sup>*</sup> Instead, figure out how large an array you need from the beginning, and allocate that shape for `time` only once. In general it is faster to over-allocate than it is to resize.

Comment: So, the problem is that I don't know the size of the array, that I want, in advance. So, I iterate over and increase the size of the array one at a time. Like this

`n = 1` 

`time = sci.zeros((1,1), 'double')`

and

`for (i in something):`

`time.resize((n+1), 'double')`

What would scipy lib do, would it just copy the previous elements of the array at a new place, because that would be slow.

Comment: I would append data to a normal Python list, (or list of lists), and then convert it to a numpy array with `time=np.array(time)` after the size is fixed.

Answer (score 4):

The resulting `time` array being just a [Numpy Array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.html), you can use standard Numpy methods for manipulating them, such as [numpy#insert](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html#numpy.insert) which returns a modified array with new elements inserted into it. Examples usage, from Numpy docs (here `np` is short for `numpy`) :

```
>>> a = np.array([[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]])
>>> a
    array([[1, 1],
           [2, 2],
           [3, 3]])
>>> np.insert(a, 1, 5)
    array([1, 5, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3])
>>> np.insert(a, 1, 5, axis=1)
    array([[1, 5, 1],
           [2, 5, 2],
           [3, 5, 3]])
```

Also, `numpy#insert` is faster than `numpy#resize` :

```
>>> timeit np.insert(time, 1, 1, 1)
    100000 loops, best of 3: 16.7 us per loop

>>> timeit np.resize(time, (20,1))
    10000 loops, best of 3: 27.1 us per loop
```