# 2 dimensions array of unknown size in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am pretty new at python and numpy, so sorry if the question is kind of obvious. Looking on the internet I could not find the right answer.
I need to create a 2 dimensions (a.ndim -->2) array of unknown size in python. Is it possible? I have found a way for 1 dimension passing through a list but no luck with 2 dimension.

example

```
for i in range(0,Nsens):
    count=0
    for l in range (0,my_data.shape[0]):
        if my_data['Node_ID'][l]==sensors_name[i]:
            temp[count,i]=my_data['Temperature'][l]
            count=count+1
        else:
            count=count
```

Where temp is the array I need to initialize.

Comment: Very new myself.  I think you will help yourself the most by looking at the NumPy module and how it handles multidimensional arrays.  (Technicality: Python doesn't have multidimensional arrays.  You can, however, have a list of lists.)

Comment: i would store data into dict of 1-d array first, having sensor_name as key.  Then when you read all data i construct 2d array at that time you know how many sensors you have

Comment: from what I can see in your example maybe your code could be vecorized, you don't need a loop and you can get your resulting array by indexing. would be useful if you could give some example data

Answer (score 3):

This shows a fairly high-performance (although slower than initializing to exact size) way to fill in an array of unknown size in numpy:

```
data = numpy.zeros( (1, 1) )
N = 0
while True:
    row = ...
    if not row: break
    # assume every row has shape (K,)
    K = row.shape[0]
    if (N >= data.shape[0]):
        # over-expand: any ratio around 1.5-2 should produce good behavior
        data.resize( (N*2, K) )
    if (K >= data.shape[1]):
        # no need to over-expand: presumably less common
        data.resize( (N, K+1) )
    # add row to data
    data[N, 0:K] = row

# slice to size of actual data
data = data[:N, :]
```

Adapting to your case:

```
if count > temp.shape[0]:
    temp.resize( (max( temp.shape[0]*2, count+1 ), temp.shape[1]) )
if i > temp.shape[1]:
    temp.resize( (temp.shape[0], max(temp.shape[1]*2, i+1)) )
# now safe to use temp[count, i]
```

You may also want to keep track of the actual data sizes (max count, max i) and trim the array later.

Comment: @user1842972: Does the code in the answer work for you?  If yes, please remember to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Given your follow-up comment, it sounds like you are trying to do something like the following:

```
arr1 = { 'sensor1' : ' ', 'sensor2' : ' ', 'sensor_n' : ' ' }   #dictionary of sensors (a blank associative array)
                                                                #take not of the curly braces '{ }'
                                                                #inside the braces are key : value pairs
arr1['sensor1'] = 23
arr1['sensor2'] = 55
arr1['sensor_n'] = 125

print arr1

for k,v in arr1.iteritems():
    print k,v

for i in arr1:
    print arr1[i]
```

The [Python Tutorials on Dictionaries](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) should be able to give you the insight you are seeking.

Answer (score 0):

in numpy you have to specify the size of the array while initializing. Later on you can expand the array if needed.

But remember expanding the array is not recommended and should be done as a last resort.

[Dynamically expanding a scipy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546080/dynamically-expanding-a-scipy-array)